How do I force macOS to respect Firefox as my default browser?
I have Firefox set as my default browser, but when I select text and right-click to "Search With Google" it invariably opens in Safari.
I have tried the Desktop & Dock > Default Web Browser setting in System Settings and the defaultbrowser tool installed with homebrew.
As a workaround I have created a "Search Google With Firefox" as a contextual menu item (added as a service in Keyboard Shortcuts). However this is less than ideal because this item appears at the bottom of the contextual menu and I must consciously pause to avoid the selecting the existing macOS "Search With Google" in order to scroll down to the the item I have added.
I want nothing to do with Safari. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks.

Which seting in System Settings are you referring to? Do you remember the terminal command you tried and where you got it from?

"Default web browser" is in system settings under "desktop and dock."   I don't remember the terminal command I used.

I tried the defaultbrowser tool installed with homebrew but no luck.

The "Search With Google" option is not something built into OS X that opens up a search engine using the default browser, it's actually a custom "service" that is built into the contextual Services Menu
You can enable/disable or edit services under System Settings -> Keyboard ->  Keyboard Shortcuts -> Services, where the "Search With Google" is listed under "Searching". Removing/unselecting the existing one will remove it from that list.
Your only option would be to program a custom Service using Automator, and then use that option under the "Services" dropdown .
